Можно ли собрать образ Fedora самому?
Я установил Fedora и настроил её под себя, могу ли я както собрать свой образ этой системе в ISO файл чтобы в дальшейшем при переустановке системы я мог не проводить настройку заного?
Или есть ли возможность както переносить все данные?

Системные настройки прог хранятся в /etc. Твои - в ~/. tar сvf в помощь.

Для того, чтобы в дальнейшем при переустановке системы не проводить настройку снова, достаточно сделать образ диска, любым инструментом Acronis, CloneZilla, dd и т.п. И восстанавливать по мере необходимости.

а могу ли я собрать образ чтобы потом устанавливать на другой пк?
